# In the following code I am getting the error "Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds. Index must not exceed 512. "

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

I want to apply the box filter and for some reason an error is showing up. Since I am very new to coding, I am not able to fix it myself as well.

Why am I getting the error

> Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds. Index must not exceed 512.
>
> Error in filters (line 31); convolutionResult = convolutionResult + image(x, y) * filter(i + halfFilterHeight + 1, j + halfFilterWidth + 1);

in this code?

```matlab
function output = myConv(image, filter)
image=imread("figures\Lenna.png");
filter=imboxfilt(image);

    [imageHeight, imageWidth] = size(image);
    [filterHeight, filterWidth] = size(filter);
    
    % Initialize the output image with zeros
    output = zeros(imageHeight, imageWidth);
    
    % Calculate the half-width and half-height of the filter
    halfFilterHeight = floor(filterHeight / 2);
    halfFilterWidth = floor(filterWidth / 2);
    
    % Perform convolution using nested loops
    for m = 1:imageHeight
        for n = 1:imageWidth
            % Initialize the convolution result for this pixel
            convolutionResult = 0;
            
            % Iterate over the filter
            for i = -halfFilterHeight:halfFilterHeight
                for j = -halfFilterWidth:halfFilterWidth
                    % Calculate the corresponding pixel in the image
                    x = m - i;
                    y = n - j;
                    
                    % Check if the pixel is within the image boundaries
                    if x >= 1 && x <= imageHeight && y >= 1 && y <= imageWidth
                        % Perform the element-wise multiplication and accumulate
                        convolutionResult = convolutionResult + image(x, y) * filter(i + halfFilterHeight + 1, j + halfFilterWidth + 1);
                    end
                end
            end
            
            % Assign the convolution result to the output image
            output(m, n) = convolutionResult;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You using x for the vertical position makes the code more confusing than it needs to be. So I might have missed something, but I don’t see any reason that error could happen. Are you sure this is the function that is running? The error message says the error happens in a function “filters”, not “myConv”.

Comment: Use the MATLAB debugger.  At the command line type the following: dbstop if error. Then run your code. When the error occurs the code will pause with all variables intact. Examine them to figure out sizes etc. and why the error occurred. Then backtrack in your code to figure out why the variables are not the sizes you expected.